# Google Sheets color row if date is closest to today's date

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

If possible, I would like to have a color schema applied to the table.

For instance, the cell that has the closest date to today will be green
The cell that has the furthest date to today will be red.

Note the date in the cells automatically changes and it's not static.

[image: date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **red color: `=IF(MIN($B$2:$B)=$B2, 1)`**
- **green color: `=IF(MAX($B$2:$B)=$B2, 1)`**

  [image: 0]

  [image: 0]